# Create an GCP asset feed to monitor key rotation

Tags: google-cloud-platform, eventtrigger, google-cloud-kms

I want to create an asset feed that would only monitor key rotation for a specific keyring. I don't really know what I put in the "--condition-expression" in order to filter out the key rotation event and the keyring. I have created an asset feed to monitor the asset CryptoKeyVersion with no other filter and it works fine. But I couldn't find any information on the format of what the "--condition-expression" should look like. I've tested this but it didn't work.

```
gcloud asset feeds create test-feed \
--project=PROJECT-ID \
--asset-types="cloudkms.googleapis.com/CryptoKeyVersion" \
--pubsub-topic="projects/{Project}/topics/{Topic}" \
--condition-expression="'name' == '//cloudkms.googleapis.com/projects/{project-id}/locations/global/keyRings/{key-ring-name}/cryptoKeys/*' && 'eventType' == 'google.cloud.kms.key.update'"
```

. I'm not sure if this would help but when key rotation happens, this is the message payload that is sent to a pub/sub.

```
{
  "asset": {
    "ancestors": ["projects/1234", "folders/1234", "folders/1234", "folders/1234", "organizations/1234"],
    "assetType": "cloudkms.googleapis.com/CryptoKeyVersion",
    "name": "//cloudkms.googleapis.com/projects/project-name/locations/global/keyRings/keyring-name/cryptoKeys/test-name/cryptoKeyVersions/18",
    "resource": {},
    "updateTime": "2023-06-16T19:01:59.380015Z"
  },
  "priorAssetState": "DOES_NOT_EXIST",
  "window": {
    "startTime": "2023-06-16T19:01:59.380015Z"
  }
}"
```

Answer (score 0):

The usage and format of `condition-expression`, together with some examples, are described at this [link](https://cloud.google.com/asset-inventory/docs/monitoring-asset-changes-with-condition).